# How to get databounded ComboBox to reflect changes made to a BindingList datasource

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox

I have a class that has a `String` for a name and a `int` for an ID number:

```
public class Item
{
    public int IDNumber { get; set; }
    public String Name  { get; set; }
}
```

I have a `List<Item>` of them that I used to create a `BindingList<Item>`. The `BindingList<Item>` is the `DataSource` for a `ComboBox` which I have databounded. I have the `Display Member` currently as the Name and `Value Member` currently as IDNumber.

I can change the `Name` but when I do the value of `ComboBox.SelectedText` becomes "". To be more clear say that the Name is "Dave". The user inputs "John". I want the `SelectedText` to change to "John" but it instead becomes "".

I have tried using `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private String name;

    public int IDNumber { get; set; }
    public String Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            this.name = value;
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

This will do the trick only after clicking the `ComboBox` once before using the `SelectedText` field whereas I want it to be updated when the change is made.

Does anyone know how I can get around this?

Thanks.

Comment: Please rephrase your question's title to be specific, not just a set of tags and common words.

Comment: where are you changing the name in another control or in code ? I am confused because A combo box can't change the name property because its a read only control unless your using a 3rd party.

Comment: SelectedText is the actual selected text in the combo's 'textbox'..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013973/winforms-combobox-databind-with-dropdownstyle-dropdown might help.

Comment: `but when I do the value of ComboBox.SelectedText becomes ""` - Can you please be clear in explaining this bit ?

Comment: Sorry for the vague title. New to this. I also added more information on what I'm trying to do. Thanks again everyone.

@MicahArmantrout I'm changing the name in the same WinForm using input that I collect from a messageBox which has access to the object. I just want the ComboBox to reflect the change made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [Binding Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx)

Call [Reset Bindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.resetbindings.aspx)

**Example**:

```
private BindingSource bs;

private SetupBinding()
{
    List<Item> data = new List<Item>();


    //Get Data 



    bs = new bindingsource();
    bs.datasource = data;
    combobox.datasource = bs;
    comboBox.DisplayMember="Name";
    comboBox.ValueMember="IDNumber";
}

private ShowMyMessage()
{
    MessageBox.Show(this, message, caption, buttons,
            MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, 
            MessageBoxOptions.RightAlign);
 if (bs != null)
 {
   bs.resetbindings(false);
 }
}
```

Then make sure your combobox has something selected and try selectedtext

Comment: Thanks. This worked but I had to use comboBox.Text after I changed it to a DropDownList.

Answer (score 1):

Use comboBox.SelectedValue

so you have to set its DisplayMember 
and ValueMember

like

```
comboBox.DisplayMember="Name";
comboBox.ValueMember="IDNumber";
```

and finally set your datasource

Comment: It is currently set up this way. The only thing is comboBox.SelectedValue returns the ID number instead of Name

Comment: If I inverse DisplayMember and ValueMember then it would display the IDNumber which I don't want